# Restrict variable in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, restriction

Is there a way in matlab to restrict variables in a function

For example i have a function

```
function S0 = S0Func(obj, c, delta, xT, sigma)
beta = obj.betaFunc(sigma);
xb = obj.xbFunc(c, delta, sigma);
S0 = (1-obj.tau).*(obj.x0./(obj.r-obj.mu)-c./obj.r-(xb./(obj.r-obj.mu)-c./obj.r).*((obj.x0./xb).^beta)-((delta-1).*c./obj.r).*((obj.x0./xT).^beta-((obj.x0./xb).^beta)));
end
```

where I would like to have the restrictions (obj is an object of a class)

```
0<xb<xT<1
0<c
1<delta
```

What I would like to do is to draw a 3d graph of the following with the restrictions mentioned above

```
S0Func(2.7, 1, 1, 0.3)-S0Func(c,delta,xT,0.2)<0;
```

**EDIT**
I have tried using the isosurface

```
optimalStraightCoupon = fminbnd(@(c) -(S0Function(c,1,1)+D0Function(c,1,1)), 0, 4);
[xT, delta, c] = meshgrid(0.8:.01:1, 1:.1:3, 0:.1:4);
values = S0Function(optimalStraightCoupon,1, 1)- S0Function(c,delta, xT);            
patch(isosurface(xT, c, delta, values, 1), 'FaceColor', 'red');
view(3);
```

I get some output, but it is not correct as the restriction on xT is violated.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What would you like to happen if the user calls your function with arguments that don't satisfy your restrictions? Do you want an error to be thrown?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I have updated the question with further information.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve.  I expect that you know that you can write statements such as (pseudocode):

```
if c>=0 exit
```

which, in a sense, restricts your function to operate only on values which meet the defined constraints.

The foregoing is so simple that I am sure that I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it appears you wish MORE than a just 3-d graph. It appears you wish to see this function as a FUNCTION of three variables: c, delta, xT. So a 4-d graph. In that event, you will need to simply evaluate the function over a 3-d mesh (using meshgrid or ndgrid to generate the points.)

Then use isosurface to visualize the result, as essentially a higher dimensional contour plot. Do several such plots, at different iso-levels.

Comment: I want a graph in three dimension of (c, delta, xT) which satisfies that the difference in S0 is less than zero as well as the restrictions are satisfied.

Comment: And, again, this is an isosurface!!!!!! Why not try it, rather than just telling us what code you want us to write for you. help isosurface

Comment: I have tried the isosurface. But I still do not know how I make sure that the restrictions is satisfied. I will edit the question with the isosurface attempt

Answer (score 0):

I would just return NaN when your constraints are violated.

Just add following lines to your function (preferable before the calculation to save time)

```
if delta <= 1 || c <= 0 || ... % I assume you can write them yourself
   S0 = NaN;
   return
end
```

Plot will not draw NaNs.

Though as you input `c,delta,xT` it's the question why they are set to *invalid* values in the first place. You could save some checks and therefore time if you assure that beforehand.